# With Pandas, how to get the data frame imported from a website, after properly selecting values from the drop down in the website?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

1. In the website 'http://www.barcindia.co.in/statistic.aspx' by default, the data table for the values 'Across Genres' & 'Top 10 Advertiser' as in the two drop-downs is displayed.

   *Refer Image: [Default Page with 'Across Genres' & 'Top 10 Advertiser' selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8WKb.png)*
2. I have to get the data frame with the values 'Sports' & 'Top five channels'. Since the web URL is not changed for different values, I can't use the URL.

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something automatic, you can use a `Phantomjs` to create `csv`files with the categories you wish. Then you can process it with `python` and `pandas`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Inspect` the table on your browser (`left click > Inspect`) and then find the `<table ...>...</table>` element and do `left click > Copy > Copy element`. I did it using Chrome, but you can do it with any browser. You can then put that string into a variable and read it with pandas using the read_html method.

This is what I got:

```
html = '''<table class="stat" id="advertiser"><tbody><tr><th width="62">Rank</th><th width="135">Advertiser</th><th colspan="3">Insertions</th></tr>  <tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th width="70" class="bordtop dnone">Last Week</th><th width="70" class="bordtop"> Week 30</th><th width="70" align="right" class="bordtop dnone">Gain / Loss</th>  </tr><tr><td width="62">1</td><td width="135">HINDUSTAN LEVER LTD</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td><td width="70">177869</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width="62">2</td><td width="135">RECKITT BENCKISER (INDIA) LTD</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td><td width="70">42053</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width="62">3</td><td width="135">BROOKE BOND LIPTON INDIA LTD</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td><td width="70">27737</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width="62">4</td><td width="135">PROCTER &amp; GAMBLE</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td><td width="70">25208</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width="62">5</td><td width="135">CADBURYS INDIA LTD</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td><td width="70">24894</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width="62">6</td><td width="135">SUPER CASSETTES INDUSTRIES</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td><td width="70">20724</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width="62">7</td><td width="135">PATANJALI AYURVED LTD</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td><td width="70">20080</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width="62">8</td><td width="135">GODREJ SARA LEE LTD</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td><td width="70">18198</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width="62">9</td><td width="135">GODREJ CONSUMER PRODUCTS LTD</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td><td width="70">17569</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width="62">10</td><td width="135">ITC LTD</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td><td width="70">16445</td><td width="70" class="dnone">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan="5" class="titlebott">TOP 10 Advertiser *Across Genre : All India (U+R) : 2+ Individuals, To get this data on your Twitter timeline, tweet with #BarcTweet Top 10 Advertisers</td></tr></tbody></table>'''

df = pd.read_html(html)[0]

df


0   1   2   3   4
0   Rank    Advertiser  Insertions  NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN Last Week   Week 30 Gain / Loss
2   1   HINDUSTAN LEVER LTD NaN 177869  NaN
3   2   RECKITT BENCKISER (INDIA) LTD   NaN 42053   NaN
4   3   BROOKE BOND LIPTON INDIA LTD    NaN 27737   NaN
5   4   PROCTER & GAMBLE    NaN 25208   NaN
6   5   CADBURYS INDIA LTD  NaN 24894   NaN
7   6   SUPER CASSETTES INDUSTRIES  NaN 20724   NaN
8   7   PATANJALI AYURVED LTD   NaN 20080   NaN
9   8   GODREJ SARA LEE LTD NaN 18198   NaN
10  9   GODREJ CONSUMER PRODUCTS LTD    NaN 17569   NaN
11  10  ITC LTD NaN 16445   NaN
12  TOP 10 Advertiser *Across Genre : All India (U...   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

This might not be the best way to do it, but it works for a one-shot.